# Multidimensional array to array string

Tags: php, arrays

Find Below my array result

```
 Array
    (   
     [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [task_id] => 1
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [task_id] => 28
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [task_id] => 43
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [task_id] => 44
                    )

            )
    )
```

I would like to store task_id as a string as below

```
Array(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 28,43, 44
)
```

I tried with implode it does not work can anyone plz help me out in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

```
foreach ($arr as &$item) {
    $item = implode(',', array_map(function ($i) { return $i->task_id; }, $item));
}
```

Each item of your array is an array of stdClass instances with the property `task_id`. With `array_map` I change it to an array of integers and then I only have to use `implode` and to affect the result to the current item.

Answer (score 1):

ideone: http://ideone.com/MnUohR

```
    <?php

//simulating your array

$x = new StdClass();
$x->task_id = 1;
$y = new StdClass();
$y->task_id = 28;
$z = new StdClass();
$z->task_id = 43;

$object = [

    [0 => $x],

    [

    1 => $y,
    2 => $z

    ]];

//converting the objects to array
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);

$new_array = [];

//implode
foreach($array as $k1 => $a){

    $new_array[$k1] = implode(', ', array_column($a, 'task_id'));

}

var_dump($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could do two `foreach` loops like:

```
foreach ($arr as $k1 => $a1) foreach ($a1 as $a2) $barr[$k1][]=$a2['task_id'];
print_r($barr);
```

See a little demo here: http://rextester.com/ACKZ42424
`$barr` is the new array.

**Edit:**  Ahhh, sorry, I misread quite a few details. Just noticed that you want the elements to be concatenated as a string. And the array contains StdObjects and not arrays ... Just as a little exercise - even if nobody is interested - here is my corrected solution again:

```
foreach ($arr as &$a1){ $t=null; foreach ($a1 as $a2) $t[]=$a2->task_id;
    $a1=join(',',$t);
}
print_r($arr);
```

This time the conversion is also done "in-place" ...
see here: http://rextester.com/JLO86317